# Instalacion de Sentrifugo HRM

Tags: xampp

Tratando de instalar este hrm en windows y utilizando XAMPP me da este error autoload() ya no es compatible, use spl_autoload_register() en su lugar en C:\xampp\htdocs\HRM\install\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php en la línea 45
?Cómo puedo resoloverlo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.